# How do I generate route based on distance in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am looking for a program that can produce routes based on distance criteria. For example, I give a start point and an endpoint that are the same and I want 5-10 different routes which start and end there but are about 5 miles long. Is there anything out there that can do that?

I know that Google Maps can do that with just a start and end but no distance parameter. I just want to have distance be a parameter and have the start and end points be the same.

Please check this link for reference: [routeshuffle](https://routeshuffle.com/planner)